# 49 plots arranged in a 7x7 matrix

Tags: r, plot

I don't know if this question is trivial, but...

I'm trying to plot a group of variables in a similar form as a PAIRS plot.

But instead of using the same variables in the row and columns of the graphic I would like to have diferents variables. For exemple, if I have a dataset with X1,...,X7 and another dataset with Y1,...,Y7.

I've tryed with layout and par(mfrow) but as I want to cross 7 variables x 7 variables it gave me an overflow error.

Is there any way to do this plot matrix 7x7?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this using `pairs(...)` in base R, but here's a `ggplot` solution, assuming your x- and y-values are in dataframes named `df.x` and `df.y`.

```
# create a sample dataset - you have this already...
set.seed(1)         # for reproducible example
df.x <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:50,350,replace=T),nc=7))
df.y <- 2*df.x + rnorm(350,sd=5)
colnames(df.y) <- paste0("Y",1:7)

# this makes the plot  - you start here.
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)      # for melt(...)

xDT <- data.table(melt(cbind(id=1:nrow(df.x),df.x),id="id",value.name="xval",variable.name="H"),key="id")
yDT <- data.table(melt(cbind(id=1:nrow(df.y),df.y),id="id",value.name="yval",variable.name="V"),key="id")
xy  <- xDT[yDT,allow.cartesian=T]

# simulates pairs() in base R
ggp = ggplot(xy,aes(x=xval,y=yval))
ggp = ggp + geom_point()
ggp = ggp + facet_grid(V~H, scales="free")
ggp = ggp + labs(x="",y="")
print(ggp)
```

[image]

This assumes, but does not test, that the number of rows in df.x and df.y are the same.

You do not necessarily need `data.tables` to do this, but it's likely to be faster if your datasets are large, and the syntax is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! its exactly what I needed. I didn't know this library (ggplot2), because I have always worked with basic R (plot, pairs, etc)